# How to include one component template into another?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I'm using ionic 5.0.0 application andIi have a chat page and home page in it. I want to include the chat page into home page. equivalent to `ng-include`.

I have added the **`exports[]`** in my **`chat.module.ts`** as seen below

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { ChatPage } from './chat.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ChatPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [ChatPage], // --> Here it is
  declarations: [ChatPage]
})
export class ChatPageModule {}
```

Then I imported chat module in my **`app.module.ts`** as follows

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { PopoverPageModule } from './popover/popover.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { GlobalFunctions } from '../providers/global-functions';
import { AuthGuard } from '../providers/security/auth-guard';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
import { HttpProvider } from '../providers/http/http';
import { HttpAngularProvider } from '../providers/http/http-angular';
import { HttpNativeProvider } from '../providers/http/http-native';
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation/ngx';
import { NgxUiLoaderModule } from  'ngx-ui-loader';
import { IonicGestureConfig } from '../providers/IonicGestureConfig';
import { HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ChatPageModule } from './chat/chat.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    HttpClientModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule, 
    PopoverPageModule,
    NgxUiLoaderModule,
    ChatPageModule // --> Here it is
  ],
  providers: [
    HttpProvider,
    HttpAngularProvider,
    HttpNativeProvider,
    GlobalFunctions,
    AuthGuard,
    StatusBar,
    ScreenOrientation,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    { provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG,useClass: IonicGestureConfig
  },
    HTTP
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then I have added the chat component selector in my `home.page.html` as follow.

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title text-center>HOME</ion-title>                
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content  class="homepage-content no-scroll" >
<ion-row>
...
</ion-row>

<ion-row>
 ...
 </ion-row>

<ion-row>  
<app-chat></app-chat> <!-- Here it is -->
</ion-row>

</ion-content>
```

But when I run my application I'm getting below error in console.

[image]

Here is my **`chat.page.ts`**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.page.scss'],
})
export class ChatPage implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Here is my **`home.page.ts`**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpProvider } from '../../providers/http/http';
import { GlobalFunctions } from '../../providers/global-functions';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation/ngx';
import * as _ from 'underscore';
import { NgxUiLoaderService } from 'ngx-ui-loader';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
...
}
```

See my code structure of both chat module and home module. Both are different modules.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show the error.

Comment: @Adrita Sharma Error added

Comment: home.page.html is a component right? and part of which module? I dont't see it in app.module

Comment: Hii Abhilash..!! make sure you are using correct selector for that <app-chat> , Is this is the same in the Chat.module.ts file ?

Comment: Hi  HaSnen Tai I have added chat.page.ts file

Comment: Show Homepage component

Comment: Please, show firsts lines of chat-page.component.ts

Comment: It would be nice if you can show online demo in fiddle

Comment: Hi Daniel  I have already added chat page component.

Comment: Hi Adrita Sharma So you are saying i need to import Home module also in app.module.ts ?

Comment: I am saying HomePage is a comonent and must be part of some module. Which module?

Comment: Is it possible that you have a loginPageModule and home.page.html is part of this module?

Comment: In any case, you have written in some html of your `LoginPageModule` `<app-chat></app-chat>` and your error is precisely that you have not imported the `ChatPage` module in `LoginPageModule`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `HomePage` component  is not declared in `app.module`,

> You need to import `ChatPageModule` in the module where `HomePage`
>   component is declared.

Answer (score 1):

One Page can not be used in other page. For this purpose ionic have components which makes small portion of whole screen/page.

It can be done in the following way:

Instead of chat page, create chat component and then use it in your pages/components where ever you want.

Use the selector of your chat component inside your parent component/page.

In child component ts file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat-component', // <---- This is the selector name
  templateUrl: './chat-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat-component.scss'],
})
```

In parent component/other pages HTML file:

```
<app-chat-component></app-chat-component>
```

Also create the components.module file and import all the components which you want to use in the pages then in page.module file import ComponentsModule.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have two different modules and you want to use it in a different module. 
Here is an example of how the Hello component is being shared by the app component. 
The working example here.

This is done in the same module. If you want you can follow the same.

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-viewchild-example-cazvny

Comment: It is working fine when i'm adding chat component as a declaration in home module. But i cannot declare the chat component in any other modules. Since it is showing "move the declaration to some other module which is importing both chat and home modules".

Comment: @AbhilashShajan The declaration of a single component must be in the parent module, to use a component in different modules, you need to create what is called a shared module, this shared module would be the one that declares the component and also to export it, so that any module of your application that wants to use it, can import the shared module.

Comment: Yes Daniel I have imported the chat module into my home module as you said. Now I'm able to see the chat template in my home template. But the problem is home page template disappeared. chat template just replaced the home template. How to see both?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have a loginPageModule and home.page.html is part of this module?

You do not need to import `ChatPageModule` into `AppModule`, you must import `ChatPageModule` into `LoginPageModule`.

---

In any case, you have written in some html of your `LoginPageModule` `<app-chat></app-chat>` and your error is precisely that you have not imported the `ChatPage` module in `LoginPageModule`.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of including a page itself inside another page.

What I would expect to see is for you to generate a component with the commandline like:

```
ionic generate component components/chat
```

Then you would get a group of  `chat.component.ts` (scss, html, etc) files.

Refactor everything out of the `app-chat` into the component.

Then you will need to make your own shared module so that you can reuse it on more than one page:

- [Using Custom Components on Multiple Pages in Ionic - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=za5NaFavux4)
- [Creating a shared module for Ionic App | meumobi Dev Blog](http://meumobi.github.io/ionic/2017/08/23/creating-shared-module-ionic.html)
- [Organize Shared Components in an Ionic 4 App | AngularFirebase](https://angularfirebase.com/snippets/how-manage-shared-components-in-an-ionic-4-app/)